# I'm trying to change the font on my website, but no matter what I try it won't work

Tags: html, fonts

So I'm trying to change the font of my displayed text, but no matter what I do it just stays at the default font. This is my current code:

```
<p font style="font-family: Garamond; color:DarkCyan; font-size: 40px;">Cross Country 2019: Bedford Bulldogs</p>
```

The color and size of the words is fine, but the font just won't change. Any ideas?

Comment: Garamond is not a web-safe font, you have to manually import it through html or css in order for it to work

Comment: when using inline css (which is not recommended btw), the syntax is style="font-family:Garmond;"; etc.. remove the excess 'font' word prior to style. font-style  is there to style your text as italic etc. (and you may need to import the font depending on the font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no use of that 'font' as attribute. Make sure that you have imported those fonts if they are no already preinstalled. An example:

```
<p style="font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif; color: DarkCyan; font-size: 40px">
```

These are available in Google Fonts for free:

```
font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;

font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
```